# Maven build failure: "error while writing test: could not create parent directories"

Tags: java, maven

When trying to run `mvn test` on Windows, my tests run fine, but on CentOS 7 I get this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.403s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 27 10:54:06 CET 2020
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/119M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project GenericTests: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/gitlab-runner/builds/5KQvSgfo/0/webdriver_projects/webdriver_bv/test_dir/src/test/java/genericTests/Contact/InputMaxLengthTest.java:[18,7] error: error while writing InputMaxLengthTest: could not create parent directories
```

This happens with a few other tests too, although not all of them. I don't understand why. These tests don't interact with folders and in fact aren't particularly different from any other test.

The only file system interaction I have is that I take screenshots and place them in a folder, using `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`, but I have permissions on that folder. And it happens even when I comment out the file writing instructions so I don't know if it's that.

On top of adding a screenshot feature, I've since changed my `pom.xml` to have

```
<maven.compiler.source>13</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>13</maven.compiler.target>
```

and I have to point to the JDK 13 location via `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-13.0.2` before running `mvn`. It must be either of those things. What could be the cause? Consider that this works just fine on Windows.

I've tried:

- deleting the screenshot instruction (didn't work)
- changing the compiler source/target to 8, as it was before (didn't work)

I didn't want to try to delete the culprit tests one by one to see if all tests had this problem or not as that would be time consuming.

EDIT: I also ran `dos2unix` in every file of the project, but the result is the same.

Here's the line where I take a screenshot and write to a file, done in every single test:

```java
@After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        // Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
        if (OSChecker.isWindows()) {
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("screenshots\\" + formatScreenshotFilename()));
        }
        else {
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("screenshots/" + formatScreenshotFilename()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Really using maven-compiler-plugin 2.3.2 ? Please upgrade to most recent version ....

Comment: If it is not the plugin version, I can only think of the obvious differences between Windows and Linux `src/test/java` should have needed rights. The file paths are case sensitive.

Comment: If the tests run fine on Windows and don't run on Linux environment, then I suspect it could be a line endings issue? "dos2unix" command will be useful to fix the line endings temporarily. you could also add config to .gitconfig for line endings

Comment: @VimalDavid ran dos2unix on every file in the project -- same result

Comment: Can you log the destination file value for the else branch? Is it a valid value? Then check if parent directory exists `destFile..getParentFile().exists()`

Comment: @khmarbaise Upgraded to 3.8.1 and it worked, please post your comment as an answer so I can accept

Comment: You can use / as path separator on windows or if you want to be purist, use `File.pathSeparator`

Comment: Try to run maven with -X option - that will provide additional debug output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should upgrade your configuration to use most recent version 3.8.1 of [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) cause you are using a very old version.